# RDP over VPN with Dell NetExtender failing

Tags: vpn, rdp

I have just installed the Dell SRA Virtual Appliance (ExSSLVPN).

This works in conjuction with RSA authenticating over PAP (Can't get chap/mschap or mschapv2 to work. Always says invalid un/pw combo).

The RSA server uses RADIUS to hit the AD server to auth users.

I can use the Dell NetExtender tool fine and get an IP on my remote network just fine.
I can ping all of my machines. I can access all of my file shares.
The only thing I cannot do is RDP. I have disabled NLA on the particular machine I am trying to get to. No luck. I am in the access list and I can remote to the machine fine if I am on the physical remote network.

There must be a setting I am missing somewhere.

Example:

Local Network: 192.168.1.0

Remote Network: 192.168.2.0

Local Network Machine IP: 192.168.1.10

Remote Server attempting to RDP into: 192.168.2.10

Once I startup the NetExtender and the VPN client gives me an IP on the remote network (192.168.2.2), I can ping the remote server (192.168.2.10) but cannot RDP into it. I get the standard "computer not found, check that rdp is enabled on remote machine" message.

If I am onsite at the remote network on a different client machine, let's say (192.168.2.5), I can remote into the remote server (192.168.2.10) just fine.

Comment: Telling us what happens (or doesn't happen) and what messages you get (if any) when you try to RDP would be helpful.

Comment: Added as much as info as I could to the question. Not really getting errors as much as it is just not working.

Comment: Are you connecting by name or ip address?

Comment: I am using IP, but I can ping the remote server by both IP and FQDN just fine.

Comment: Take a look at the RDP rule in the Windows Firewall on the server. It may be blocking connections from non-local ip addresses.

Comment: @joeqwerty that was it. I could not find the specific rule, but, disabling the windows FW did the trick. Thanks man. I'll mark as answer if you post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the RDP rule in the Windows Firewall on the server. It may be blocking connections from non-local ip addresses.